# Construction of layout in CSS

Tags: css, html, dhtml

How do i go about piecing each and every div together?

I'm learning how to code in CSS and i'm fairly new, and i want to piece 3 - 8 pieces of the divs in each row. Once i've pieced some together, they appear uneven inside the dreamweaver IDE (and also inside the browser display).

Also, how do i get to resize them automatically? I've been trying width:100%; but all i'm getting is weird resized shapes and sizes.

If you don't get what i mean, my webpage technically looks like this

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|                                                                                |
|                               background image 1                               |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                       |            |                    |                      |
|     bg img 2          |   bg img 3 |  bg img 4          |    bg img 5          |
|                       |            |                    |                      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|                                                                                |
|                           background image 5                                   |
|                                                                                |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

but everytime i put my divs in the same row with a containing div for each row, i.e

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="bg1" width:100; height:20;>
        <div id="bg2" width:150; height:20;>
            <div id="bg3" width: 250; height:20; >
                <div id="bg4" width:130; height:20;>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it gets all jumbled up at the same location. Am i doing something wrong?

Would appreciate if someone could tell me a step by step solution...

Once again, i want to go about doing:

1. Construction of website with CSS for the layout.
2. Auto resizing of entire page according to web browser size.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to start with pixel sizes for your `<div>` pieces... and then later think about how to do the resizing part. :)  That way you can focus on the layout you are wanting, first...

Comment: pixel sizes? you mean something like <div id="bg1" width:100px; height:20px;></div>?

Comment: Your divs are not receiving the width and height attributes you want for them. Inline CSS is specified through the style attribute. For instance, style="width: 100px; height: 20px;" will set the width and height inline.

Comment: Yeah, but you'll want to eventually put your CSS styles into some sort of file_name.css :)  But for using CSS inside of your `<div>` tags, you will need to use the `style=""` attribute, like this: `<div id="bg1" style="width:100px;height:20px;"></div>`

Comment: The px (pixel) units can be changed later to percentages if need be... but starting with pixels will more easily help you achieve the idea of what you want.

Comment: oh, oh. my styles are declared inside a .css file, just that for this example i took it out, easier to look at. :P i'll focus on the layout first then, see how it goes.

Comment: but am i using the class and id structure right?

Comment: Yes, no problem about those; I can help you more later on... gotta get some sleep now... but if no one else helps you out later, I'll check back!  For now... just try using the `style=""` attribute for whatever CSS structure you need.  Later on... just move those `style` items into a text CSS file... and assign the matching classes or ids to the styles in your CSS file like: #id_name { width:100px; } .class_name { width:200px; }

Comment: alright, now i'm stuck at the portion where my divs stack together on top of each other. how do i go about telling dreamweaver that my divs should be next to each other instead of on top of each other?

Comment: `float:left;`  But yeah... like the other people are saying... it's not a bad idea to eventually look into using a CSS template or "framework" to do grid layouts a bit easier...

Comment: hmm, float:left doesnt work for me, it's still stacked on top of each other. But i'm looking into css templates on the web, maybe i can learn a thing or two there. not to say you guys havent helped me a lot, i've learnt a lot of stuff just by posting this question here today. thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you have all the `<div>`s stacked inside each other. See my answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477596/construction-of-layout-in-css/9478285#9478285 ) for a example of how to have it working with floats (but like I say in my answer, there are many ways to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use inline styles for prototyping something when you're a beginner. They're too hard to edit live. It will slow the process way way down.

You sound new to this, but that's cool! We all started somewhere.

Create your 5 divs first, and give them each a unique ID. IDs are for things that only appear on the page once. Classes are for things that appear more than once, or might at some future point appear more than once.

Then link a css file that your a separate declaration for each div. You're on the right track with width=100% for responsive design, although in practice it's often something like 92% even for a "full-width" div, because a little spacing is nice, and borders and padding add to the overall width. A 90% width div with 6% padding is always wider than the window itself (greater than 100%) which makes for strange behavior, so keep the box model in mind from the start.

Here are some tips I wish somebody had broken down to me early on:

Nowadays things are a LOT easier than they used to be for rapid prototyping CSS. The best way to figure this stuff out is to edit the stylesheet live in Chrome Developer Tools. Download and install Chrome if you're not using it already. Control click on your div and choose "Inspect Element." Play around in the inspector, and see how all the CSS styles can be edited live by doubleclicking on them and entering new values. If you click the "resources" tab you can see your whole stylesheet at once, and similarly edit the properties, and even add new ones. The best way to see what's happening with sizing is to temporarily declare an outline like:

```
#mydiv1 {outline: 2px dashed red;}
```

because outlines don't add to the width of the element, unlike borders. Then when you're done you can remove the outline declarations. Also keep in mind that any changes to a document's CSS in Chrome Dev Tools will be lost when you navigate away. So copy and paste your work into a text editor as you go.

If you're interested in responsive design, which is great, once you're getting good at all of the above, buckle in and read Ethan Marcotte's book:

http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Marcotte's instructional approach is to start with pixels and then translate into percentages and ems in the stylesheet, but it doesn't need to be that way. You can design "live" with those variables in the browser.

hope this helps!

Comment: yeah, i'm using chrome, it helps a lot in debugging and whatnot! :D thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get rid of Dreamweaver. It's a hindrance. And has always been buggy. The sooner you get rid of that crutch, the better off you will be.

Secondly, looking at your example, I see a template for the old slice-n-dice photoshop into a table methodology. Replicating that with DIVs in CSS is rather pointless.

Third. If you truly need a table (data) keep it a table. Nothing wrong with that.

Fourth. The key to all of this is understanding floats and what contains floats. Most of the CSS grid systems base everything off of that. I'd take a look at 960.css and start playing with that a bit. It should help point you in the right direction of understanding what is going on.

Comment: If i don't use Dreamweaver, what can i use?

And how would you suggest i go about constructing my website? It's not going to have a lot of words, i was thinking about a more content-centric website, you know, lots of pictures, maybe just 1 or 2 paragraphs of words.

I was thinking of using (in fact, i used photoshop to slice and dice, then ported it over to dreamweaver, but people i've talked to talked me against it, saying that tables are inefficient and etc. That's why i'm learning CSS right now so i can better utilize what web design has to offer.

Comment: Tables go hand-in-hand with slice-n-dice. You can't really ditch one of the bad habits and not the other. Ya gotta quit cold turkey. ;) As for losing dreamweaver, use almost anything else. Ideally, a dedicated text editor. On OSX, Coda and X-code are both good options. On Windows, I'm a fan of Notepad++

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `<header>` tag for the topmost part, and a `<footer>` tag for the bottom part. Clearly it works also with `divs`, but in my opinion it's cleaner that way.

That means that you'll have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
 <header id="img1">
 </header>
 <div id="img2">
     &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div id="img3">
     &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div id="img4">
     &nbsp;
 </div>
 <div id="img5" class="newrow">
     &nbsp;
 </div>
 <footer id="img6">
 </footer>
```

that could represent your desired structure pretty well. To style this, you can use `CSS`, and there are many possible solutions to the problem. One simple solution would be to set `<header>` and `<footer>` to 100% width, and to float all `<div>`s  but the last one to the left, so that the remaining content (the other `<div>`s, in this case) will be on its right. Then you just have to set the width on all the `<div>`s, if you want you can even set it in percent, just make sure that it adds up to 100 or else you'll have a gap on the right. Also, you should put a `margin-left` on the last div to ensure that the content is placed properly.

This could be coded like this

**CSS**

```
body > header,
body > footer {
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
}

body > div {
    float: left;
}

#img2 {
    width: 30%;
}

#img3 {
    width: 10%;
}

#img4 {
    width: 30%;
}

#img5 {
    width: 30%;
}

body > div.newrow {
    float: none;
    margin-left: 70%;
}
```

You can see a little example of this code [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ramsesoriginal/sdfUV/show/), and you can grab it's code and play around with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/sdfUV/).

but like I said, there are many ways to achieve the layout you want, this is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

As per your layout, what you want, Its better to have semantic HTML markup.

Example

```
<div class="containerWrap">
<div class="fullWidth"><img src="/imagePath"/></div>
<ul class="container">
<li id="bg1"><img src="/imagePath"/></li>
<li id="bg2"><img src="/imagePath"/></li>
<li id="bg3"><img src="/imagePath"/></li>
<li id="bg4"><img src="/imagePath"/></li>
</ul>
<div><img src="/imagePath"/></div>
<div>

CSS Would be 

.fullWidth{
width:100%;
}
.containerWrap ul li{
list-style-type: none;
height:20px;
float:left;
}
#bg1{
width:100px;
}
#bg2{
width:150px;
}
#bg3{
width:250px;
}
#bg4{
width:130px;
}
```